# Corruption of non-volatile shared variable

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I know about the visibility guarantees of `volatile`. I'm **not** asking about that.

I just had this code in review:

```java
class MyController {
  private int someId = -1; // uninitialized state

  public void handleRequest() {
    // gets called from multiple threads, incoming HTTP requests
    var id = getSomeId();
    // do something involving the id
  }

  private int getSomeId() {
    if (this.someId == -1) {
      this.someId = fetchIdFromSomewhereElse();
    }

    return this.someId;
  }

  private int fetchIdFromSomwhereElse()
  {
    // expensive but idempotent, always returns a positive value
  }
}
```

A colleage commented that i must make the `MyController#someId` variable volatile or otherwise i'd *run the risk of reading corrupted values*.

I assume that it is not possible for `getSomeId()` to return a negative value (since `fetchIdFromSomewhereElse` never returns a negative value). Correct me if i'm wrong here, please.

### Question: in the code above, is it ever possible for `getSomeId()` to return a value that was never written to the `someId` instance variable?

Does the answer change with data type and architecture? int/long, 32bit/64bit?
I assume that

- variables will always be aligned on word boundaries
- and thus, the CPU will always write the entire variable to memory in one atomic operation
- and thus, a `long` on a 32bit machine might cause trouble here.

I **do** realize that `fetchIdFromSomewhereElse` may get called several times, not just once.

I was not able to produce an example where an int or a long gets corrupted on a modern 64bit processor.

Comment: You will not get a value that is not written to that variable. You may get any one of the values that were written to that variable if it is not volatile.

Comment: Java guarantees that you will never see "corrupted" values (values that were never written and just pulled out of thin air).  For 64 bit primitives running on a 32 bit system, it is permissible in the spec to see "word tearing," that is one half of the 64 bit value written while the other half has not been updated yet.  This would certainly look a lot like corruption.  On 64 bit systems this sort of word tearing is disallowed.

Comment: @markspace Where can I find the guarantee that `fetchIdFromSomewhereElse` won't modify `this.someId` directly and store intermediate values into it as it executes? What makes that not a legal Java optimization?

Comment: You'll have to get that guarantee from the library or person who implemented `fetchIdFromSomewhereElse()`.  This stuff isn't magic.  That method either accesses `someId` (which I note is private, so it shouldn't be able to be accessed) or it doesn't.  There shouldn't be any guesswork here.

Comment: @markspace How can the person who implemented it know whether or not the implementation optimized it to avoid using a temporary? Are they supposed to look at the generated bytecode? How would that even help? The runtime can optimize the code too.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The language makes guarantees that the runtime is not allowed to violate.  Without some specific issue though it's too broad to really discuss, you're basically asking for the entire language spec to be explained to you.  If you have a question, I'd suggest posting it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I agree that `fetchIdFromSomewhereElse()` could theoretically modify the field. But in this case it doesn't. And honestly, such code would have a much harder time getting an approval; modifying state in a method that returns and is called `fetch` is just horrible programming.

Comment: @marstato My issue is that the optimizer makes it modify the field even though the code only has a single assignment to that field. For example, if the code to fetch the ID has `x = 0; if (bar) x = 1; return x;` can the compiler optimize out `x` and make all those writes apply to `someId` directly? I know in C and C++, the optimizer is allowed to do that, and I thought it was a legal Java optimization but am not certain.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I would have to find the relevant section in the JLS, but I am.very sure that a Java compiler/runtime is not allowed to do that to variables stored on the heap, precisely because it brings issues like this. On the stack it's an entirely different story though

Answer (score 0):

## No

Not with an `int`. From [the Version 8 JLS, 17.7.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7):

> #### 17.7. Non-Atomic Treatment of double and long
>
> For the purposes of the Java programming language memory model, a single write to a non-volatile long or double value is treated as two separate writes: one to each 32-bit half. This can result in a situation where a thread sees the first 32 bits of a 64-bit value from one write, and the second 32 bits from another write.
>
> [...]

For me, this clearly states that any JVM implementation must be able to read & write 32 bits atomically. Combine this with 17.6. :

> #### 17.6. Word Tearing
>
> One consideration for implementations of the Java Virtual Machine is that every field and array element is considered distinct; **updates to one field or element must not interact with reads or updates of any other field or element.** [...]

And it is clear that the write to the int field is atomic.

---

But it also concludes that shared non-volatile `long`s and `double`s can behave in a very undesirable way when used across threads and without `synchronized`. I have to agree to my colleague that it is a good idea to just mark every shared variable `volatile` unless there is a clear performance hit that cannot be tolerated.

Also from 17.7.:

> [...]
>
> Writes to and reads of references are always atomic, regardless of whether they are implemented as 32-bit or 64-bit values.
>
> [...]

which implies that the JVM has to enforce volatile semantics for any non-primitive anyways, making the `volatile` on reference fields superfluous at worst.

---

Thanks @markspace for giving me the term `word tearing` to google for! :)

Comment: What prevents the compiler from optimizing `this.someId=fetchIdFromSomewhereElse();` into first setting `this.someId` to refer to an integer whose value is zero (or something else) and then having `fetchIdFromSomewhereElse` change that value, allowing a window in which another thread could read a value from `this.someId` that is neither -1 nor the correct value? Heck, what prevents `fetchIdFromSomewhereElse` from modifying `this.someId` internally with intermediate values? What law requires the compiler to use a temporary or intermediary location?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz the code in `fetch` is not relevant. te JLS forbids the compiler and runtime from touching the field without an explicit assignment statement in the source. I asked whether the field can have a value that was not assigned to it (as would happen with word tearing), but i never asked about *where* that assignment is. If `fetch` touches the field and the outer method ends up with one of these intermediate values the answer is still "No" because the value obtained was explicitly assigned.